# How to generate a cartesian product of two internal tables?

Tags: abap

I actually have a simple requirement. 
There are two tables given:

[image]

What is the most performant way to get a third table with all possible combinations of the values from these tables, starting with the values from the first table? Well like 1A, 1B, 1C, 2A.....etc.

Is there any standard framework I could use for this?

Comment: Are those tables database tables?

Comment: no, internal tables

Comment: It's a very basic algorithm which can be written in one statement. As it looks like a [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you should at least explain what you tried, etc. I don't understand why there should be a "framework" for that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Sandra! The actual problem was a bit more complicated and I just simplified it as much as I could, but you are totally right, it's very simple and I could solve it with just one statement.
I already requested the question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two tables. In that case use a `CROSS JOIN` as described [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/26/abap-news-release-7.51-cross-join-open-sql-abap-cds/)

Code quotation from the article:

```
REPORT ZZZ.

SELECT t000~mandt, t000~mtext, t100~*
       FROM t000 CROSS JOIN t100
       WHERE t100~arbgb = 'SABAPDEMOS'
       ORDER BY t000~mandt, t100~sprsl, t100~msgnr
       INTO TABLE @DATA(itab).

BREAK-POINT.
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes it actually what I need, but for internal tables and I was wondering if there is any elegant way to do this without nested loops

Comment: I don't think there is a cross join for internal tables, so loops would be the only solution for you if the data does not come from the database. If it does however then you should consider doing the cross join before putting the data in internal tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest one-liner I can imagine

```
TYPES: tt     TYPE TABLE OF c WITH EMPTY KEY,
       tt_res TYPE TABLE OF char2 WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(t1) = VALUE tt( ( '1' ) ( '2' ) ( '3' ) ).
DATA(t2) = VALUE tt( ( 'A' ) ( 'B' ) ( 'C' ) ).
DATA(l2) = lines( t2 ).

DATA(result) = VALUE tt_res(  ).

DO lines( t1 ) * l2 TIMES.
  result = VALUE #( BASE result ( t1[ ( sy-index + l2 - 1 ) DIV l2 ] && VALUE #( t2[ sy-index MOD l2 ] DEFAULT t2[ l2 ] ) ) ).
ENDDO.
```

Although, it uses loop, but not nested loop. This notation is not very readable but nevertheless short. I am sure there is also way to do it with `VALUE..FOR` but I believe it will be more verbose.

Of course, you should adjust types for your real tables and test on bigger dataset.

Answer (score -1):

You can load all values to internal tables then make nested loop for fill new internal table with concatenate columns.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. For particular those table in my question it's not a problem. But when I have two tables with over 100 entries, i was wondering if there are nice way, may be build in in abap can be used